# Ionic 3 - Display lock screen when we minimized the app

Tags: background, ionic3, lockscreen

In Ionic 3, we need to display the lock screen if app is minimized or goes to background if we open any other app.

Thanks
AK

Answer (score 0):

I got it how we can implement the above logic.

```
  platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
        //logic when the application is in the background
        this.navCtrl.push(LockScreenPage);
      });

      platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
        //logic when the application has been resumed after being paused.

      });
```

But anybody have any idea where we can have it commonly in the application, because I am having 16 pages in my app. If I create BaseApp and extends with all the 16 pages then this code would executes 16times. Any other way to implement this logic. Is it OK we use it in component.ts?

Comment: add it in app.component